# Htaccess how to add static text to url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to make example.com **/productName** to example.com **/product/productName**

 I just want to add static text **/product/** in mid to url how can i add this with .htaccess file to url structure? I already tried this code but it did not worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#hiding parameter name and product.php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /product.php?productName=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to keep your htaccess along with folder product(not inside product folder).

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##Making rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine ON
##rules for external redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(product)\.php\?code=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
##Rules for internal rewrite here.
RewriteRule ^(product)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?code=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't worked for me again prodcut name not hiding this time.

Comment: @4NaT, could you please do let me know what sample url you are hitting?

Comment: i'm working on turkish website called **klasya.com** when user click product product.php receiving get parameter then making sql query to database. klasya.com/prodcut.php?code=wa this example i made query **where = wa** frankly i want to change product.php to **product/** and  want to hide parameter name **product/wa** finally looks like **https://klasya.com/product.php?code=wa** to **https://klasya.com/product/wa**

Comment: @4NaT, I have updated rules now, could you please do check my updated rules once? Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. If you have any other rules too then place these top of your htaccess file, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: it's working thanks, but website structure is broken idk why weird. **https://klasya.com/urun/wa** urun mean -> product

Comment: @4NaT, do you want to have these rules only for `wa` I mean `code=wa`? Then I can fix rules to only look for that, let me know.

Comment: i have 8 products so it changing to code=ig or code=tg etc. but product/ will be static

Comment: @4NaT, ok if 8 products are there then it should be Good with current rules. What is broken then? is it js/css for site? Please do let me know.

Comment: i inspected console and  i saw 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token' javascript error title and content is changing to product

Comment: @4NaT, ahhh then I believe its not related to htaccess in my humble opinion.

Comment: i voted u thanks for ur effort but without htaccess working good https://klasya.com/urun?code=wa